# Correct terminology for "obj.X" VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, function, properties, methods, terminology

I am reviewing some code and I realized I don't remember the correct terminology for something. I believe if I had the following code

```
pnlOne.Visible = False
```

Would the "visible" part be considered a method, function, or what? I am learning VB alongside JavaScript, and in JS it would be a method. Is it the same for vb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VB.net, that is a "property". Properties in VB.net and C# as essentially glorified methods for getting and setting a value. (They actually compile down to something like `get_Visible` and `set_Visible` methods.)

Answer (score 1):

`pnlOne` is an instance of a class and `Visible` is its property

Answer (score 1):

`Visible` could be *either* ..

1. a [Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8ae41a4.aspx); *or*
2. a [Field (called "Member Variable" in VB)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke6sh835.aspx)

.. depending on how it is declared. Both Properties and Fields are specializations of "Members"<sup>1</sup>. See [Differences Between Properties and Variables in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk5e8eth.aspx).

I *suspect* `Visible` is a Property in this case, and it will be for all standard [Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx) types .. however, to verify this either way requires knowledge of the Type of the object named by `pnlOne`.

---

<sup>1</sup> 
[Methods (or "Sub/Function Procedures")](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xxtk8kx.aspx) are a different kind of Member and it is *not appropriate* to call either a Property or Field a "Function" or a "Method". (Note: various references *inconsistently* make a distinction between a [Method and a Procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yse67234.aspx); in VB.NET they an be thought of as synonyms.)

Nit: the *correct* term in JavaScript would be [property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators); properties can *evaluate* to function-objects and can thus also can be considered *methods* when they do so - usually when `this` is used meaningfully. In any case, the code would have to be different (e.g. `jsObj.set_Visible(true)`) if a method was used.